# SwiftUIで2本指でのドラッグができません。

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUIで2本指でドラッグしたいのですが方法がわかりません。DragGestureには2本指にするようなプロパティは見当たりませんし、Composing Gestureで組み合わせてみても上手くいきません。どなたか方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃれば教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: 私が調べた限りでは、SwiftUIでは2本指ジェスチャーはサポートされていないようです。どうしても必要な場合は`UIViewRepresentable`を使って`UIView`+`UIGestureRecognizer`を使って実現しないといけないようです。ドラッグではなく2本指タップですが、[こちらに実装例](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/132827)があります。

Comment: そうなんですね。それでいくら探してもみつからなかったんでしょうね。素早い回答ありがとうございました。